# SSRS- How to download the rdl file and the shared datasets associated to that report from the report manager?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

There is one SSRS report running in the Report Manager and I have to do some changes in the report whereas I do not have the rdl file or shared datasets of that report.

In the Reporting Manager, if I right click on that report and click on "Download", it downloads the rdl file but not the shared datasets.
Is there anyway that I can download the rdl file and the shared datasets of that report from the Reporting Manager and do the required changes in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to above question is-
To download the rdl file- right click the report and click on Download and it will save the rdl file of the report.
To download the rsd-shared datasets of the report- there is one folder named: Datasets in Report Manager, click on Datasets, then right click on the datasets that are associated to the report and click on download.

Thank you!